# How To upload datastore data to csv file in google cloud storage?

Tags: google-bigquery

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/datastoretobigquery#ingestionjob

How To upload datastore data to csv file in google cloud storage?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box way to do that. If you could do that incrementally, you could use a code similar as the one below:

```
/** GCS Service */
private static GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(new RetryParams.Builder()
        .initialRetryDelayMillis(10).retryMaxAttempts(10).totalRetryPeriodMillis(15000).build());

/**
 * Create a file on a specified bucket
 */
public static void writeFile(String bucketName, String filename, String fileContent) throws IOException {
    GcsFilename gcsFile = new GcsFilename(bucketName, filename);
    GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(gcsFile, 
            new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("text/csv").build());
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
    out.write(fileContent.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```